# Update value inside a collection with where clause inside a complex json - Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a PG table with a json field named **data** with the following structure

```
{
  "location": "",
  "department": [],
  "languagesKnown": [
    "English,Spanish"
  ],
  "maritalStatus": "Single",
  "kidsCount": 0,
  "relations": [
    {
      "type": "father",
      "name": "somename",
      "status": "live"
    },
    {
      "type": "Mother",
      "name": "somename",
      "status": "Notlive"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I update all relations with status with value 'NotAlive' with 'No More'

PG VERSION :14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `jsonb_set`:

```
select col from (
  select col, jsonb_set(col, '{relations}', jsonb_agg(s.relation_updated)) as col_updated
  from (
    select *, jsonb_set(relation::jsonb, '{status}', 
              CASE
                 WHEN relation ->> 'status' = 'Notlive' THEN '"No More"'::jsonb
                 ELSE relation -> 'status'
               END) as relation_updated
    from mytable t,
         jsonb_array_elements(t.col->'relations') as relation
   ) as s
   group by col
) as s
```

1. Extract all array elements using `jsonb_array_elements()`, and use `jsonb_set()` to update status within the array elements. The CASE clause does the condition check.
2. aggregate array elements into one array using `jsonb_agg`

The update statement can be :

```
update mytable t
set col = u.col_updated 
from (
  select col, jsonb_set(col, '{relations}', jsonb_agg(s.relation_updated)) as col_updated
  from (
    select *, jsonb_set(relation::jsonb, '{status}', 
              CASE
                 WHEN relation ->> 'status' = 'Notlive' THEN '"No More"'::jsonb
                 ELSE relation -> 'status'
               END) as relation_updated
    from mytable t,
         jsonb_array_elements(t.col->'relations') as relation
   ) as s
   group by col
) as u
where u.col = t.col
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9GSREGDt)